# How to refresh a selector?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have 2 components which is Component A and Component B , Component A is calling component B via selector , the app-team-users is the selector , it is calling data from API and then populating it on the table which is working fine.

In Component A I called the component B selector , in Component A I have a feature where I create a user or save a user .

How do we refresh or call the app-team-users selector so that if I save a user from Component A then the table on Component B will refresh which is the  app-team-users will refresh ? cause they are seperate component. Maybe anyone has idea or enlightenment ? Thank you very much. Good day.

#Component A save user code

```
  saveUser() {
    if(this.createUserForm.valid) {
      this.accountService.create(this.createUserForm.value).pipe(
        finalize(() => {
          this.isInProgress = false;
        })
      ).subscribe({next: (res) => { this.notificationService.showSuccess('User has been created successfully.');
          //if user is created refresh the selector
        },
        error: (err) => {this.notificationService.showError('Something went wrong, Try again later.');
          this.isInProgress = false;
        },
        complete: () => {
          this.isInProgress = false;
        },
      });
    }  
  }
```

[app-team-users table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNlNk.png)

#Code for calling the selector Component A

```
  <form [formGroup]="modelForm" >
            <app-team-users [selectedNewUser] = "newUsers" [selectedTransactionTeam]="modelForm.value.teams"
                [selectedTransactionUser]="modelForm.value.users" (transactionUserEvent)="transactionUserEvent($event)"
                (transactionTeamEvent)="transactionTeamEvent($event)">
            </app-team-users>
        </form>
```

#app-team-users code

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.transactionUserTable.dataSource = new MatMultiSortTableDataSource(this.sort, this.CLIENT_SIDE);
    this.transactionUserTable.nextObservable.subscribe(() => { this._transactionUserPageEvent(); });
    this.transactionUserTable.sortObservable.subscribe(() => { this._transactionUserPageEvent(); });
    this.transactionUserTable.previousObservable.subscribe(() => { this._transactionUserPageEvent(); });
    this.transactionUserTable.sizeObservable.subscribe(() => { this._transactionUserPageEvent(); });
  }

private _transactionUserPageEvent() {
    this.isTransactionUserLoading = true;
    this.transactionUserTable.data = [];
    this._userProfileService.getUserProfileTableDropdown(
      this.accountId,
      this.transactionUserTable.pageIndex + 1,
      this.transactionUserTable.pageSize,
      this.searchTransactionUserInput.nativeElement.value,
      this.transactionUserTable.sortParams,
      this.transactionUserTable.sortDirs
    )
      .pipe(
        finalize(() => this.isTransactionUserLoading = false)
      )
      .subscribe({
        error: err => this._notificationService.showError(err),
        next: res => {
          this.transactionUserTable.totalElements = res.totalItemCount;
          this.transactionUserTable.data = res.items as UserProfileDropdownDto[];
          this.totalData = res.totalItemCount;
          this.currentDisplayedData = res.lastItemOnPage;
        },
        complete: noop
      });
  }
```

Comment: you might want to refactor this so there is a service to host the data the two components need to share... that's the more usual way, and will give you less headaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it via Observables.

Emit a value to an observable when a user is created in the first place. You can either pass the entire *user* value inside the observable and use that data to populate the second component from the front side itself. Or you can just pass a value, just to know in the second component that something has been created in the first one, then you call the same api to populate in the second component.